# Send Data from iPhone 4S to Bluetooth device

Tags: iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a question. Hope some one would help me.

I want to send some data(in struct fromat) from my iPhone 4S to a bluetooth device over Bluetooth.

The bluetooth device has support for BLE 4.0.(as required by iOS development)

So I guess Core Bluetooth Framework should help.

I just wanted to know if it is possible to send command from iPhone to my bluetooth device.

If yes then how. If someone can help me ,it would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  Apple has two samples for CoreBluetooth which you can find at developer.apple.com; both are for the Mac, but the same CB code will work on the iPhone.

You will need to learn something about Bluetooth, and in particular, what profiles your device supports.  But assuming it supports some profile that does what you want to do, there's no reason you can do it from your iPhone 4S.